# does FastMember support anonymous types?

Tags: .net, reflection, fastmember

I'm using [FastMember](https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/) for an alternative to reflection.  In the source, I see there is a unit test for anonymous type support, but I'm getting a NotSupportedException when I attempt to TypeMember.CreateNew() for an anonymous type.  Are they not supported?

Answer (score 0):

They are supported but not with `TypeMember` - you should be using `ObjectAccessor` instead like:

```
var obj = new {A = 123, B = "def"};
var accessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(obj);
Assert.AreEqual(123, accessor["A"]);
```

Comment: Anonymous types are generated at compile-time, therefore I don't think they belong to the DLR and that's why you can use `TypeAccessor` instead of `ObjectAccessor`

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but I just had the same doubt and you can simply do:

```
var anon = new
{
    Prop1 = "a",
    Prop2 = "b"
};

MemberSet members =
    TypeAccessor
        .Create(anon.GetType())
        .GetMembers();
```